# Generating regular points on 3d polygon surface?

Tags: postgis, 3d, citygml

I have some CityGML buildings and I imported them into postgis database using 3d citydatabase. I want to generate points on buildings surfaces just like in the shown image. Building surfaces are stored as polygonz surfaces in Postgis. How can I generate points on these 3d polygon surfaces? Are there any function of postgis for this? Or are there any algorithm for this purpose ? Can I create a function in postgis for this purpose?[image]

Comment: Your questions are interesting, but there are too many of them -- this format encourages one clear question. Yes, you can always create a function. But, first, perhaps an example of one of you polygons. You say in the title regular points, regular how? The is a function ST_PointOnSurface which works in 3d, but your question as is stands is far too vague to know if that might help or not.

Comment: with "regular" I mean equally spaced points. For instance, distances between every point must be 2 meters. Is it possible via ST_PointOnSurface? @JohnBarça

Answer (score 0):

This is doable though probably more complicated than you described. A plan is to :

1. Extract all surfaces from CityGML. I have a [tool](https://github.com/Killermachine/gml2obj) that can do this for individual buildings. On another note, FME is a really good tool to convert CityGML to triangle mesh.
2. sample points from this mesh. There are many tools, you can check [this](https://github.com/yuqli/trimesh2pointcloud) tool that we have.

I have also written a blog post on similar matters [here](http://yuqli.com/?p=2982).